# Using Dependency Properties on multiple user control instances

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I created a user control that have multiple dependency properties that work correctly. My problem is that when I create multiple user control instances and bind the same DP on the same external property and I modify the second instance of the User Control the input for the first instance will be also modified and I don't want that. Is there something like a x:Shared property for DP's that will keep each DP with his instance?

I don't think this question needs code attached because is somehow a general question.

Regards

Comment: It should behave exactly like that when you bind to the same property of the same view model object. You could perhaps create multiple instances of the view model class, but that is hard to tell unless you show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: post some sample code that shows your problem